# Zend Form button with an image

Tags: zend-framework, button, zend-form

I started using Zend forms, how can i have :

```
 <button id="show" type="button">
    <img width="18" height="18" alt="Calendar" src="assets/calbtn.gif">
 </button>
```

using Zend_Form_Button.

I tried this but it didnt work  :

```
$btn = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('show');
$btn->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
$btn->setLabel(' ');
$btn->addDecorator('Label', array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'img','placement'=>'append','src'=> 'assets/img.gif')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use css to set a background for the button and then use

```
$btn->setAttr('class', 'btn_class');
```

And in css

```
.btn_class {
    background-image: url('assets/img.gif');
}
```

I am not sure how you could do what you want without creating a new custom Zend_Form_Element. But There is also Zend_Form_Element_Image that probably does exactly what you want.